# How can I copy an edge with the knife tool?

Tags: modeling

This is the following of my previous question 'Why can't I add an edge loop?'. I put an edge loop and extended the edge on the last quad with the knife tool (shortcut K). How should I do to keep the line created with the knife tool parralel to the point of reference i.e. how can i have the blue line the same length as the red one. Thanks.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Try to use the Knife tool when subdivision modifier is disabled.

Comment: Afaik you can't do that easily (well, you could use either View or Custom [Transform Orientations](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/object/transform/transform_control/transform_orientations.html) but that's may be quite cumbersome task, depending on the case), it's just that it could be done in another way / easier. Why don't you cut that edge with Loopcut if there's a quad ?

Comment: I don't know why but when I add an edge loop the last quad is not included. The topology is surely bad but I didn't manage to find the reason. So i was wondering if there is a way to measure an edge and make a copy or a tool to keep the edge parallel.